# Session Management - Multiple Sessions That Can Expire And Invalidated?

Tags: session, cookies

I'm designing a session management system for a side project of mine, and I'm wrestling with finding a simple solution to the following requirements:

**Requirements:**

1. A user can have multiple sessions
2. All sessions for a user can be invalidated at once
3. Sessions for a user expire after 30 minutes

I've seen approaches for allowing a user to have multiple sessions that naturally expire (eg Redis and generated keys).  However, this approach doesn't offer a straightforward way to invalidate all sessions belonging to a user since each key for a session is a randomly generated value.

I've also seen approaches where a user can have multiple sessions by tracking the generated session ID's for a user in an RDBMS table.  While this makes it easy to invalidate all the sessions belonging to a user, I now have an additional process that must invalidate/remove expired sessions because the database (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) doesn't do this on it's own.

Is there an approach where I can have all 3?

Comment: May I ask why you want mutliple sessions instead of a single one, or even no session at all?

Comment: I want to allow multiple devices, browsers, etc. to be able to authenticate with the same credentials, but be treated as independent sessions.  The "no session at all" does bring up some interesting thoughts though.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: From the point of view of your web server, a session is a session, meaning that there should not be anything a priori which would prevent your server from having a mobile and desktop session for the same user.

Comment: Correct, but let's say the browser logs out.  How would the web server know to invalidate that session or not? Perhaps a mobile device is still using it?

Comment: So you want multiple devices sharing the _same_ session?

Comment: No, I want to allow for each device to have it's own session, but I can invalidate all of them at once.  Furthermore, I want them to expire naturally without a 3rd party process cleaning them up after they expire.

Comment: I would store tokens in the database, each linked to a user ID, and then invalidate them all at once.

Comment: Right, but now the expiration/clean up of expired tokens is something additional I'd have to do.  I'm asking if there's an approach this isn't necessary.

Comment: Nowadays most sites, Stack Overflow included, store the session in a browser cookie.  It would be difficult to find a way to delete this cookie remotely.  So I think you will have to store state for each token which is extant among the various devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from your question, I can come up with a solution using redis itself. Instead of having a separate key for each session, you can [Redis Hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) for all the sessions you want.

Basically, the keys of the hash would be your unique session IDs which would be generated on the client side and the values would be any sort of data you want to maintain per session (you can save a JSON as a string).

And you can then apply a TTL on the entire hash to expire all the keys at once. Thus satisfying all you requirements